# Python >> matplotlib: Get the number of lines on a current plot?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Is there a way to get the number of lines currently on a matplotlib plot? I find myself setting colors in a colormap using a counter and multiplier to step through the color values--which seems rather un-pythonic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the `Line2D` objects in an `axes` are stored into a list

```
ax.lines
```

If you use only simple line plots, the lenght of the above list is enough.

If you use `plt.errorbar` the situation is a bit more complicated, as it creates multiple `Line2D` objects (central lines, vertical and horizontal error bars and their caps).

---

If you want to automatise the colours to assign to lines you can create a cycle like this

```
import itertools as it
colors = it.cycle(list of colors)
```

and then call the next color with `colors.next()` and restart from the first after it gets to the last

Comment: Is there a difference between `ax.get_lines()` and `ax.lines`? When I check, they are equal...

Comment: They might well be the same. Did you check the source code? In ipython you should be able to get the code with e.g. `ax.get_line??`

Comment: Ah. I should have thought about checking the source code :) Seems quite the same to me: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1831   Thank you!

Comment: Yep, they are the same, except for the string representation